# There is no single replacement for the Transform API - android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently updated my android studio to version -`2021.2.1 Patch 2`
My gradle distribution version is `7.3.3`

When I build my project I get the following error

```
API 'android.registerTransform' is obsolete.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
The Transform API is removed to improve build performance. Projects that use the
Transform API force the Android Gradle plugin to use a less optimized flow for the
build that can result in large regressions in build times. It’s also difficult to
use the Transform API and combine it with other Gradle features; the replacement
APIs aim to make it easier to extend the build without introducing performance or
correctness issues.

There is no single replacement for the Transform API—there are new, targeted
APIs for each use case. All the replacement APIs are in the
`androidComponents {}` block.
For more information, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-    updates#transform-api.
To determine what is calling android.registerTransform, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: core
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone stuck in this issue
Add this `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` to your `gradle.properties`
This will help you identify which library is causing the issue.

In my case it was 3rd party library which caused this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because i have just upgraded the gradle version recently so i tried to downgrade it